# Safari rending svg text tspan's in wrong positions when using a RTL language

Tags: html, svg

Safari is ignoring positions of tspan's with a `svg text` when text is a RTL and inverting them.

Here is the fragment:

```
<svg height="240" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- Border -->
  <rect width="120" height="120" style="stroke:pink;fill:white;stroke-width:3;" />
  <path d="M60,5 L60,115 M5,60 L115,60" stroke="pink" />

  <g transform="translate(60,0)">
    <text x="60" y="60" tabindex="0" focusable="true"
      style="fill: rgb(96, 94, 92); font-family: 'Segoe UI', wf_segoe-ui_normal, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-anchor: middle;">
      <tspan x="0" dy="0">دولة الإمارات العربية</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" dy="20" style="fill: lightsalmon">المتحدة</tspan>
      <title>دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة</title>
    </text>
  </g>

  <style>
    <![CDATA[
    text {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    ]]>
  </style>
</svg>
```

This is how it looks in Chrome and Firefox:

[image]

But this is how it looks in Safari:

[image]

It seems like Safari is ignoring the `dy` attribute of the second `tspan`, and probably positioning first. Is this an issue with Safari's rendering engine or is there something that can be done to fix this?

---

][3]][3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### State 2023: Obviously, a webkit (core) issue (not specific to safari's webkit implementation)

I could reproduce this bug in a virtual machine running linux mint with these webkit-based browsers:

- web/epiphany
- midori

A bug you should report:

- [Webkit bug reports](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs)
- [Apple Safari](https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html)

Related webkit bug report concerning right-to-left issues:
["SVG  with Hebrew text incorrectly shifted"](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78711)

### Workaround: insert a [left-to-right mark](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H34.html) in between the "lines" `<tspan>`:

```css
svg {
  height: 20em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

tspan {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="120" height="120" style="stroke:pink;fill:white;stroke-width:3;" />
  <path d="M60,5 L60,115 M5,60 L115,60" stroke="pink" />
    <text x="60" y="60" 
      style="fill: rgb(96, 94, 92); font-family: 'Segoe UI', wf_segoe-ui_normal, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-anchor: middle;">
      <tspan x="60"  y="60" dy="0">دولة الإمارات العربية</tspan>
      <!-- left-to right mark -->
      <tspan dx="-0.5em" class="br">&#x200E;</tspan>
      <tspan x="60"  dy="20" style="fill: lightsalmon">المتحدة</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

We're actually switching from *right-to-left* to *left-to-right* between the pseudo-line `<tspan>` elements.

The `dx="-0.5em"` compensates the introduced extra space (... although, the Right-to-left mark/character shouldn't take any space).

See also ["How do I separate right-to-left text in an SVG without English letters in between?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74064690/how-do-i-separate-right-to-left-text-in-an-svg-without-english-letters-in-betwee)

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what the correct behavior should be, but Safari clearly has its own ideas about it. For what it’s worth, if you put the each `<tspan>` in its own `<text>` element, it seems to do what you expect on a variety of browsers.

```
<svg height="240" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <!-- Border -->
    <rect width="120" height="120" style="stroke:pink;fill:white;stroke-width:3;" />
    <path d="M60,5 L60,115 M5,60 L115,60" stroke="pink" />

    <g transform="translate(60,0)">
        <text x="60" y="60" tabindex="0" focusable="true">
            <tspan x="0" dy="0">دولة الإمارات العربية</tspan>
            <title>دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة</title>
        </text>
        <text x="60" y="60" tabindex="0" focusable="true">
            <tspan x="0" dy="20" style="fill: lightsalmon">المتحدة</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>

    <style>
        <![CDATA[
    text {
            font-weight: bold;
            fill: rgb(96, 94, 92);
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', wf_segoe-ui_normal, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-anchor: middle;
        }
        ]]>
    </style>
</svg>
```